# jquery .change() not recognizing change!

Tags: jquery

I have a option select that is generating a slider. When the select option changes, the slider changes and the same way, the other way around.

I've setup an alert to fire when an option on the select is changed. This alert recognizes and fires when I change the option from the select, but when I change it from the slider, nothing fires.

I really need to get this thing to fire. Here is my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>        Demo Page: Using Progressive Enhancement to Convert a Select Box Into an Accessible jQuery UI Slider</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectToUISlider.jQuery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/ui.slider.extras.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
    body {font-size: 62.5%; font-family:"Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    fieldset { border:0; margin: 6em; height: 12em;}    
    label {font-weight: normal; float: left; margin-right: .5em; font-size: 1.1em;}
    select {margin-right: 1em; float: left;}
    .ui-slider {clear: both; top: 5em;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //demo 1
        $("#hide_me").hide();
        var abc = $('select#privs').selectToUISlider().next();

        $('.change').change(function() {
             alert("Ive been called");
        });
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>

    <body>

<form action="#">
    <!-- demo 1 -->
    <fieldset>
        <label for="speed">Select a Level</label>
        <select name="speed" class="change" id="privs">
            <option value="Read">Read</option>
            <option value="Create">Create</option>
            <option value="Update">Update</option>
            <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
        </select>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Just call the select.change in the function the slider performs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google search suggests the correct way to attach an onChange event handler for the particular slider control you're using is:

```
var abc = $('select#privs').selectToUISlider({
    sliderOptions: {
        change: function(e, ui) { 
            alert('Changed!'); 
        }
    }
}).next();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior, programmatic changes don't fire the `onchange` event (endless loop would arise in many cases if they did).

To trigger your handler, just fire the `change` event yourself, for example:

```
$('#privs').val('Read').change();
```

In your case, use the `stop` event of the slider, like this:

```
var abc = $('#privs').selectToUISlider({
    sliderOptions: {
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $('.change').change();
        }
    }
}).next();
```

[You can try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/renXW/), if you're dealing with multiple elements though, use a `.each` where you can trigger the `change` event of the `<select>` that goes with the slider you're on.

Comment: "programmatic changes don't fire the onchange event" - thank you very much @Nick Craver